# How to express these sentence in Present and Past?

Tags: grammar

Am I right between Present and Past?

1/ Do you want me to turn on/open the fan? (Present)
If the fan has number to work, Can I say , In what number you want me to put?

2/ Did you want me to turn on/ open the fan? (Past)

In what number you wanted me to put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and most important, your basic thought about present and past is correct.

> Do you want me to turn on the fan?

is proper present tense

> Did you want me to turn on the fan

is proper past tense.

Second, "open a fan" is so unidiomatic, at least in the U.S., that many would have no understanding of what you intended. (Someone repairing a fan might open it to replace a part or examine it, but that is not your intended meaning at all.)

Third, the sentences about "put" and "number" are not grammatical.

You just used the right rule in your other sentences. You start a question in the present tense with "do" (or "does"), and you start a question in the past tense with "did." So

> do you want me to put

for present, and, for past.

> did you want me to put

However, "put" is a transitive verb, which means it **requires** an object to be grammatical. So

> In what number do you want me to put it

is grammatical and present tense, and

> In what number did you want me to put it

is grammatical and past tense.

Unfortunately, neither is incomprehensible. I suspect that you are thinking about a fan that can be **set** to run at various speeds. How we would say that would

> At what speed do you want me to set the fan

or

> At what level do you want me to set the fan

or, a bit redundantly,

> At what setting do you want me to set the fan.